# How to place custom data inside mat tab group in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to display content inside `mat-tab-group` but it is not displaying even if the condition becomes true. Is there any way we can show that data?

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="selectedTabChange($event)">
  <div *ngIf="condition">Hello 1234</div>
  <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="second">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `div` with `mat-tab`:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="selectedTabChange($event)">
 <mat-tab *ngIf="condition">Hello 1234</mat-tab>
 <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
 <mat-tab label="second">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: I don't need tab, Just need to display some data based on condition